# What are the benefits or drawbacks of my primary care physician having hospital admitting privileges?

Tags: treatment, practice-of-medicine, hospital, general-practitioners

In the United States, what are the reasons for and against choosing a primary care physician who has hospital admitting privileges?

For example, if my primary care physician does not have hospital admitting privileges, and I need to check into a hospital as in inpatient, will my PCP be able to participate in my care while I'm in the hospital?  If not, will a doctor who works in/for the hospital will be 100% responsible for coordinating and/or administering my care?

Considering the time, expense, and rules involved in obtaining and maintaining admitting privileges, could it be that a PCP might tend to admit a patient to a hospital unnecessarily?